# Flexbox to change position of elements

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

Is it possible to use flexbox to do something like in this example? Basically Id like to flip elements which are in a column to be in a row when viewed in mobile. How would you do this?

```html
<p> Desktop:</p>
<table style="height: 52px;" width="331">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 103.533px;">image-icon1</td>
<td style="width: 103.533px;">image-icon2</td>
<td style="width: 103.533px;">image-icon3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 103.533px;">Text1</td>
<td style="width: 103.533px;">Text2</td>
<td style="width: 103.533px;">Text3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> Mobile:</p>
<table style="height: 71px;" width="189">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 87.1px;">image-icon1</td>
<td style="width: 87.1px;">Text1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 87.1px;">image-icon2</td>
<td style="width: 87.1px;">Text2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 87.1px;">image-icon3</td>
<td style="width: 87.1px;">Text3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible

Check below example.

I am using CSS media query `@media(max-width:768px)` to check whether the width of screen is less than 768px(can be any value less than this).

Depending on that, I am setting the direction of flex children to `column`, so that the children can stack on top of each other.

Along with that, on mobile screen, I am also setting, the display of inner containers(`.sec` class) to flex,

```
<div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
```

So that, its children will align itself in row.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;/* default value*/
}
.text,.img{
  padding:10px;
}
.sec {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

@media(max-width:768px) { /* can be anything less than this*/
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sec {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;/* default value*/
  }
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div> <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div> <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div> <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div> <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div> <div class="sec">
    <div class="img">Image</div>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thx very much, but this code is not flexing when I make my browser smaller, or I do something wrong? I tested it here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FR9P7AYOY40K

Comment: @MedienForscher ,works just fine [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/F74Bamj)

Comment: Sorry, the window was not wide enough. Everything fine now, thx very much!